# Error while closing application with alert dialog

Tags: android, android-dialog

Logcat:

```
06-13 18:25:37.534: E/WindowManager(420): Activity com.dimensionsco.thankbunny.MainActivity has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@43ef3c98 that was originally added here
```

This is the code i was using to exit application with alert dialog. But it is ending up with errors. I dont understand where i went wrong.I am running it on emulator. Could any one solve this? Thanks in advance

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "stop", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilde = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    alertDialogBuilde.setTitle(this.getTitle() + "EXIT");
    alertDialogBuilde.setMessage("DO you want to exit?");
    AlertDialog alertDialogr = alertDialogBuilde.create();

    alertDialogBuilde.setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            // go to a new activity of the app
            dialog.cancel();
            // finish();
        }

    });

    alertDialogBuilde.setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            dialog.cancel();

        }
    });

    // set neutral button: Exit the app message
    alertDialogBuilde.setNeutralButton("Exit the app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
            // exit the app and go to the HOME
            System.exit(0);
            // MainActivity.this.finish();
        }
    });

    alertDialogr.show();
}
```

Comment: Post the logcat please

Comment: This: `System.exit(0);` is horrible. Don't do that.

Comment: @323go kk, i'll replace with finish()

Comment: could anyone suggest how to post log cat data here?

Comment: Copy the important part, edit your question and put it in a code block. And never use `System.exit(0);`, it will just mess up your app.

Comment: @XaverKapeller Interestingly, when i put same code under a button, it is working fine. But when i use it under onStop() it is not working.

Comment: If we have to guess what the problem might be than your question is either not detailed enough or provides the wrong information. For starters post more of the stacktrace, not just one line. And we alreadu told you that `System.exit(0)` is terrible.

Comment: This `public void onStop()` is the main issue. Answer posted.

Answer (score 2):

You can't create UI or interact with the user in `onStop()`. Please refer to the [Activity Lifecycle documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/pausing.html). By the time `onStop()` is executed, the activity is already invisible and is being released, so you can't interrupt that process anyway. What's worse, if you *could* interact here, your `finish()` would then invoke `onStop()` again...

If you need to intercept a user-initiated exit, overwrite [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29) and prompt your dialog in there.

Keep in mind that activities may be paused and stopped for all sorts of reasons, including incoming phone-calls. You certainly wouldn't want a user to have to confirm your prompt in order to answer his phone...

Comment: i have got anther bug here. Now dialog is popping up, but "YES","No" buttons are not present in dialog.

Comment: Move `AlertDialog alertDialogr = alertDialogBuilde.create();` to below the `set***Button` calls and before the `alertDialogr.show()`

Answer (score 0):

You finish the activity from the dialog here, but the alert is not destroyed so it leaks. You need to close the dialog first, then finish the activity.

```
alertDialogBuilde.setNeutralButton("Exit the app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // exit the app and go to the HOME
        System.exit(0);
        // MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Answer (score -2):

System.exit(0) is not a good idea to close Activities, instead call finish(); System.exit calls the garbage collector and then, nothing else but the garbage collector runs in Your system. All other running processes will be paused during the gc. This method should only be used for very necessary reasons.

But, please post the complete Logcat output so that the poeple here can see exactly what has happend. Maybe we need to see more of Your code, to know where the issue is.

Anyway the reason why this error happens could be, that You are not closing Your dialog before finisish. So you have to do the following:

```
alertDialogBuilde.setNeutralButton("Exit the app", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
        // exit the app and go to the HOME
        dialog.cancel();
        finish();
        // MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not an answer to the "question," but a comment. And it has been commented.

Comment: and that the reason to give -1? comments should not as long as this what I wrote and please read completely through my answer before judging me

Comment: Nobody is "judging" **you**. However, your answer doesn't answer the question. And yes, an incorrect answer is a reason to downvote. What other reason should there be?